# How can i disable that, when i open the input keyboard my whole site gets resized?

Tags: android, jquery, html

I am making an Android app using Html and Phonegap. on one off my pages i want the user to make some inputs, but when you click on the input field the input keyboard comes up, as i wish. But the whole websites shrinks to like half the size, making it very ugly. How can i disable this and make it so, the keyboard opens above the site, not squeezing it together.

Answer (score 0):

In Android menifest file you can define window soft option like if you don't want to resize your content on open keyboard use

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
  />
```

Their are lots of option are available for window keyboard you can find their description [here](http://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/visibility.html)

Comment: Due to using Phonegap, i dont have access to the android manifest itself. Is there a way i can do this in html or using phonegaps own config file?